# Does the 128 character limit for table names include the database name and schema name?

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

Microsoft's [Database Objects documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172451(v=sql.110).aspx) states that table names can only be `128` characters. Does this include the Schema name? What about the database name?

For example, if I needed to run the following sql statement that copies all data in a source table to a destination table in a different database, I'd write:

```
SELECT *
INTO DestinationDatabase.DestinationSchema.DestinationTable
FROM SourceDatabase.SourceSchema.SourceTable
```

Now say I have a table that stores the database name, schema name, and table name for both the source and the destination tables, what size limit should I put on the columns storing these names?

Is it a 128 character limit for each part (database name, schema name, table name) or should the entire identifier (like `DestinationDatabase.DestinationSchema.DestinationTable`) only be up to 128 characters long?

Comment: Have you tried creating such a table in a test database?  This isn't exactly a hard thing to test yourself...

Comment: no. just name of the table have limit of 128 char.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's length of sysname data type nvarchar(128). It's per element (so for table separately 128).